# Facebook Share Errant Characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, facebook

When I posted my question on Facebook, the apostrophe in the title got messed up.

[image]

Comment: I was getting ready to close this as off-topic when I saw the title and the tags... But, surprise! :)

Comment: @Prob: S'my wife. I made sure she did it right :)

Comment: Did Jason put you up to this?  I have a feeling this won't be fun to fix...

Comment: No... I found the bug, I made the post, I drew the circles, Jason supervised. :-)

Comment: To me, this is a bug in Facebook, but it's doubtful they'll fix it, so we'll end up accommodating the way their system works.  Also, we might get @JasonPunyon to fix it, since you found it :)

Comment: @Jarrod: F. Did I just get a work "honey do" list?

Comment: A fix will be deployed tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I just posted another question with an apostrophe on Facebook and everything looked good!